# Body zoom для разных устройств

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать так, чтобы на компьютере масштаб body был 90%, а на телефонах 150%?

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю что вы имеете в виду мета тег viewport, что бы сайт масштабировался на мобильных устройствах нужно прописать в head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Насчёт body и 90% советую просто пересмотреть вёрстку и уменьшить ширину контейнера.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось ( Если что изначально уже @media.... стоит на минимальное разрешение сайта